# Cannot use strcpy with 2 string (segmentation fault)

Tags: c

What's wrong with this code?:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    char strs[] = "What will be printed?";
    char *str1;
    char *str2;

    strs[5] = '\0';
    str1 = strs;
    strcpy(str2, str1);

    printf("%s\n", str2);

    return 1;
}
```

I want it to print "What", instead i get segmentation fault.

I believe it has something to do with the `strcpy(str2, str1);`, but what is the explanation for that? The signature of `strcpy` is `char* strcpy(char* destination, const char* source);` and that's exactly what i did.

Could you explain that to me?

Comment: Ask yourself what `str2` points to when `strcpy(str2, str1);` is invoked? Perhaps read [strcpy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) and consider whether the `str2` argument complies with the requirements for a successful execution of that function.

Comment: You haven't initialized `str2`. So you are pretty much trying to copy data on some memory that can be anything.

Comment: @BesDollma
But if i'll initialize ```str2```, then i won't be able to change it, because it's immutable. The only thing that works is when i declare ```char str2[20]``` instead of ```char *str2;```. But i wonder if it's still possible when i use ```char *str2``` and not the other one.

Comment: Make it an array `str2[20]` or allocate some memory `str2 = malloc(strlen(str1)+1);`.  Also check `str2` after malloc (might be `NULL`).

Comment: Huh? Who says `str2` is immutable??

Comment: I've used my canonical dupe for "help I'm storing things into uninitialized pointers" so many times today that I fear I'll wear out the memory cells on the SO server where that post is stored...

Comment: @ryden who told you it is immutable? This is not Python. In C you can change any bit that you want anywhere that you want as long as you know what you are doing.

Comment: In C you can regard _string literals_ as immutable, but not strings in general. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-char-s-initialized-with-a.

Comment: That's what i meant: 
```char *str2 = "initialized";```
Here, it's still not working, even though ```str2``` is already initialized. Thats because it's immutable, don't it?

Answer (score 1):

Your destination string is not initialized - it has no memory reserved for itself. An attempt to write to it causes invalid memory access (you're trying to overwrite something completely random and unplanned) and is followed by a segmentation fault.

One clean way to initialize a string is to define a global macro variable that just sets the largest size of strings you plan on using in your code,

```
#define MAXBUF 100
```

Then in your `main` you can simply write:

```
char str2[MAXBUF];
```

And your program will work. Alternative is to use dynamic memory allocation which you will likely learn about soon.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char *src = "What will be printed?";
    char dest[100];

    int START = 0;  // start of copy
    int LENGTH = 5; // length of copy

    // copies up to LENGTH characters from the string pointed to, by src to dest. In a case where the length of src is less than that of LENGTH, the remainder of dest will be padded with null bytes.
    strncpy(dest, &src[START], LENGTH); 

    printf("%s\n", dest);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Code without explanation is not a good answer.